# OnClick event in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

my onclick event is not working in angular 2 application. Below is my code:

HTML- (home.component.html): My complete HTML Code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>Iroz-V3 - Sutherland Global Services</title>
    <link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="login_bg">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mask">
            <div id="item1" class="item">
                <div class="program-wrap">
                    <div class="log_wrap">
                        <div class="log_img"></div>
                        <ul class="log_list">
                            <li>
                                USER ID<br>
                                <input class="log_input" id="NtLogin" placeholder="NT Login ID" type="text">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                PASSWORD<br>
                                <input class="log_input" placeholder="*******" type="password">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="button" class="reset_but" value="Reset" />
                                <a class="india panel">
                                    <input type="button" class="log_but" value="Login" (Click)="login_btnClick()" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

TS-(home.component.ts): My complete TS File

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    template: `app/Components/home.component.html`
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit() { }
    public login_btnClick() {
        console.log("function called");
        alert("login");
    }
}
```

It's not even calling the function and not showing any error in console.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? The information in your question doesn't provide enough information to debug the issue. Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: It's not even call the function and also its not showing any error in console.

Comment: The information in your question doesn't provide enough information to debug the issue. Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: try using console in place of alert.

Comment: Already tried with console. Its not working. @Ankit

Comment: Could you please try once by removing id and class of your button?

Comment: nope not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `""` for the function call inside your HTML.

```
<button class="log_but" value="Login" id="login" (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

Also, as stated already, your `home.component.ts` needs to use `templateUrl` instead of `template`. You also need to create a constructor for your component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() { }
    login() {
        alert('login clicked');
    }
}
```

EDIT

As stated in the commented, your `(Click)` should be lowercase, `(click)`.

Comment: This also not working. No its not giving any console errors. :(

Comment: Just a question, are you importing CommonModule inside your home.module.ts?

Comment: No i'm not importing CommonModule @wesley

Comment: Do help I'm still stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Can you post your home.module.ts?

Comment: I posted my complete code.Kindly check my question now @wesley

Comment: Ok so you need to read what I've answered. Your `(Click)` is case sensitive if needs to be lower case. Your home.component.html shouldn't contain the `<header>` and `<body>` tags, those should be within the index.html. Your issue is the case of the `(Click)`, it should be lowercase

Comment: OMG Worked. Silly mistake. Thanks @Wesley

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<button (click)="login()">Click</button>`
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit() { }
    login() {
        alert("login");
    }
}
```

your syntax is

```
template: app/Components/home.component.html
```

change it to

```
templateUrl: './home.component.html'
```

Comment: hello @Depi use this and remove your home.component.html.       template: `<button (click)="login()">Click</button>'

Comment: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-bind-click-event-angular-2/         check this site on ur syntax